# Estimating a double sum involving fractional parts of primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, estimation

Let $$ S(n)= \sum_{p \leq n \\ k > 0} \left\{\frac{n}{(p-1)p^k}\right\},$$
where sum is taken over the primes $p$ and $n$ is natural. If $k > \log_2 n$, then the remainder term is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{p \leq n, \, k > \log_2 n} \left\{\frac{n}{(p-1)p^k}\right\} &= \sum_{p \leq n, \, k > \log_2 n} \frac{n}{(p-1)p^k}- \sum_{p \leq n, \, k > \log_2 n} \left \lfloor\frac{n}{(p-1)p^k}\right\rfloor\\
&= \sum_{p \leq n} \frac{n}{(p-1)} \sum_{k \geq \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor + 1} \frac{1}{p^k} \\
&=  \sum_{p \leq n} \frac{n}{p^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}(p-1)^2},
\end{align*}
for which an analytic expression can be obtained via the Abel summation formula. Thus, we have
\begin{align*}
S(n)= \sum_{p \leq n \\ k \leq \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} \left\{\frac{n}{(p-1)p^k}\right\} + n\sum_{p \leq n} \frac{1}{p^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}(p-1)^2}.
\end{align*}
The remainder term is expected to approach $0$ for large $n$ (as a matter of fact, it appears to decay like $1/\ln n$); now, the summation for  positive $k \leq \log_2 n$ remains. We may bound this term by
$$\sum_{p \leq n \\ k \leq \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} \left\{\frac{n}{(p-1)p^k}\right\} \leq \sum_{p \leq n \\ k \leq \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}1 = \pi(n)\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor,$$
which implies $S(n)$ behaves like $n$ for $n$ large enough (as a matter of fact, $o(n)$). However, I believe we can actually obtain a closed form though I'm not sure how.

> **Question: Is there a closed form analytic expression for the sum $$\sum_{p \leq n \\ k \leq \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} \left\{\frac{n}{(p-1)p^k}\right\} ?$$**

Comment: No. But the asymptotic is known, it is $ \sum_{p\le x} \{x/(p-1)\}+O(x^{1/2})$ whose asymptotic is found from the same argument as in the prime number theorem.

Comment: Could you link me the proof or article, please?